# Django Form with multiple buttons

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form for a voting system.  I have the candidates in a table row.  At the end of the row I have button with the candidate ID

```
<form method="post">
 <table>
   ...
   <tr> 
    <td>name</td>
    <td>campaign promises</td>
    <td><button id="candidate_id"></td>
   <tr>
   ...
 </table>
</form>
```

"candidate_id" is an actual number and unique. I would like to get that id value from the post request, so I know which candidate was selected. Im hoping its as simple as

request.POST.Something

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can provide `name` attribute to the button, say for example `candidate_id_value` as:

```html
<form method="POST">
 <table>
   ...
   <tr> 
    <td>name</td>
    <td>campaign promises</td>
    <td><button id="candidate_id" name="candidate_id_value" ></td>
   <tr>
   ...
 </table>
</form>
```

Then access this value in the view as:

```py
request.POST.get("candidate_id_value",False)
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working.  request.POST.get("candidtate_id_value") is returning False. What would I expect to get back from that line. Is it the attributes in the button?

Comment: @pat If it returns False that means `candidate_id_value` is not coming from html, can you please share your view and html correctly in the question?

Comment: I ended up finding a way for it work with htmx and pulling it from django-htmx. Its a better solution than I originally had in mind.